# Rotation issue only on iPhone 3GS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, autorotate

I seem to be having a device specific problem with this code below, as it only affects the iPhone 3GS when I test.

Basically, the interface doesn't rotate. It works fine on all iPads and iPhones newer than the 3GS. If you can help me, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        return YES;

    } else {
        return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the iOS version on the devices you're testing?  It sounds liklier to me that this is your problem, not the device itself.

Comment: The version is iOS 5.1.1, which boggles my mind as to why it won't work.

Comment: Huh.  And just to clarify, it's also 5.1.1 on the other test devices you're using?

Comment: did other apps are rotating properly in your iPhone3GS, if yes then its your code problem otherwise there might be problem in your device. Might be you have disabled the screen rotation feature.

Comment: Yes indeed. @Challenger Other apps are working fine. But my code should work though.

Comment: This is a long shot, but how did you create this view controller and transition to its view? You didn't do a `[someOtherController addSubview:thisController.view]`, did you? Because that's well known to prevent rotation events from being transmitted. But if this is the root view, or if you transitioned via standard techniques like `presentViewController` or `pushViewController`, then that wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: I have the code shown above in my app delegate, and all my view controllers, including the root view controller.

Comment: @troop231 Ok, if you're seeing this non-rotation problem at the root view controller, my suggestion is not relevant. It's more of a problem for people who find that their subsequent view controllers won't rotate. BTW, I don't think having this method in you app delegate does anything. It's a view controller method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your appDelegate didLaunch method, do you enable rotations:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
```

Comment: Why is this code required to solve the 3GS only, and yet it isn't necessary for newer iPhones?

Comment: Read the docs - you have to use this to INSURE that you get rotations. Its not optional. Now, if some OTHER app has set it maybe you get the messages. Or maybe its a "feature" of different phones that you get them. The docs say, if you WANT rotations you need to do this message - it doesn't say if you DON'T do it you won't get them.

Comment: @troop231 Did this solve the problem? If it did, great! But I have never used `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` and always get my rotation events on all devices ranging from 3GS running 5.1.1 to 3G running 4.2.1 to 4S and iPads.

Comment: @DavidH I understand what you're saying re the docs, but I can't reconcile this with my experience. And to your suggestion of "other apps" possibly turning this on, I even tried powering down devices, firing up my "Hello World" app, and rotation events are received on all of these devices without needing `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`. If I check `generatesDeviceOrientationNotifications`, by the time I hit my very first `viewWillAppear`, it's turned on for me. I'm just creating my project via "New Project" - "Single View Application", so it's not like there's some legacy code.

Comment: I don't work for Apple and thus do not have any insight into this, any more than you can see reading up on those two methods. The first sentence in the class description reads "You must call this method before attempting to get orientation data from the receiver."

Comment: The problem was the actual 3GS, and not my code after many days of confusion. The phone's accelerometer sometimes works and sometimes doesn't work for various apps. Problem solved!

Comment: Are you saying that some 3GS phones do not generate rotation events because their accelerometer doesn't work, but only doesn't work for some apps? This seems really really unlikely... I think it would be a nice closing to this thread to have a definitive answer. How can you code around some phones don't have working accelerometers???

Comment: I don't think I clarified perfectly, but, the 3GS I was using was having hardware issues.. so I used a different 3GS, and it worked perfectly. Hopefully this is clear now.